# Call methods from argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following Python code below and I'm trying to call the methods `genres(), episodes(), films()` when the *argparse* is trigged in `main()`, I read in the Wiki and in topics here in Stack, that it can be achieved by using `action=` and `const=`, but my code isn't working properly. The idea is like:

`python myApp.py --genres "Foo"` would give `genres()` the name `"Foo"`

`python myApp.py --episodes "Bar" "Foobar"` would give `episodes()` the strings `"Bar", "Foobar"`

So that, from these methods I'll call the methods in the other package that will do all the magic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8

import argparse

def genres():
    print("Gotcha genres!")

def episodes():
    print("Gotcha episodes!")

def films():
    print("Gotcha films!")

def main():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Command line interface for custom search using themoviedb.org.\n--------------------------------------------------------------')
    ap.add_argument('--genres', action = 'store_const', const = genres, nargs = 1, metavar = 'ACT', help = 'returns a list of movie genres the actor worked')
    ap.add_argument('--episodes', action = 'store_const', const = episodes, nargs = 2, metavar = ('ACT', 'SER'), help = 'returns a list of eps  where the actor self-represented')
    ap.add_argument('--films', action = 'store_const', const = films, nargs = 3, metavar = ('ACT', 'ACT', 'DEC'), help = 'returns a list of films both actors acted that decade')

    op = ap.parse_args()
    if not any([op.genres, op.episodes, op.films]):
        ap.print_help()
        quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `argparse` module is designed to parse command-line arguments and options and put them in a convenient data structure for you (`op` in your code). Once that is done, `argparse` is mostly out of the picture and you need to write regular Python code in the usual way.

```
def main():
    # The code you already have...

    if op.genres: genres(op.genres)

def genres(gs):
    # Do stuff with the genres...
```

Comment: While technically, you *can* write code that will make the `parse_args` method directly invoke arbitrary code for arbitrary arguments, it's generally not the best course of action.

Comment: This way works fine, but it's not the best approach. The use of `action=` is better, I just need to know how to use it. :)

Comment: @Juan: Why do you say the use of `action` is better? `argparse` is designed to convert command-line arguments into a format that can be easily used by the rest of the program. It's not supposed to invoke the rest of the program itself.

Comment: @Juan I think you are mistaken. Read the argparse documentation for the `action` attribute: every built-in action is focused narrowly on one thing -- how to store command-line information in the data structure. Yes, you *can* create custom actions to do just about anything. But why would that be any better than normal Python code?

Comment: @user2357112 Because I'll have something out-of-the-box calling my methods, I won't need any `ifs` or `whiles` in my code, iterating the array.

Comment: @Juan: You'd need to write a custom action class with a `__call__` method. You'd write *more* code, *more* complex, and *lose* control over what your code does. Suppose you need to do something based on the values of two arguments. `action` can't handle that; it only sees one argument. `action` is really not the answer.

Comment: I just read @FMc comment, I think I really mistaken the doc. Yeah, I think you guys are right... Thanks!!!

Comment: @Juan Also notice that the purpose of custom actions (at least judging by the example in the documentation) is not to invoke your program's business logic. Rather, it is to handle special behaviors related to storing command-line information in the data structure.